# JSoup - Grabbing URL from div class within a div id

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I roamed around, trying to find a solution on how to grab a string from a div (with id) within a webpage - more specifically, another URL. Here is the code I currently have:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wowhead.com/item=" + item_id).get();
Elements info = doc.select("div#ic" + item_id);
System.out.println(info);
```

An item id example would be 10003. I'm trying to grab the image URL corresponding to the item that's in the inner-div, but it only returns this:

```
<div id="ic10003" style="float: left"></div>
```

I also tried selecting the inner-div class called iconlarge, with this:

```
Elements info = doc.select("div.iconlarge");
```

But it returns nothing. I'm assuming it's a variable type issue, but I'm still unsure. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you more specific?what is your expected output?

Comment: I was trying to grab an image url that was stated inside a div. Expected output was this if using the is 10003: http://wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/inv_gauntlets_05.jpg
nyname00 solved my issue though. Again, sorry for the late replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be difficult using *Jsoup*. When you print your `doc` you will see that there is an element:

```
<div id="ic10003" style="float: left"></div>
```

with no content. A few lines down though, there's a script that seems to be adding the image to that div:

```
$WH.ge('ic10003').appendChild(Icon.create('inv_gauntlets_05', 2, null, 0, 1));
// and a few more lines
```

Now, *Jsoup* is only able to parse the *raw* HTML, it does not execute any scripts or apply stylesheets to elements.

Not sure if it is exactly what you're looking for, but take a look at the `meta` tags of the site:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Wowhead"> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Black Mageweave Gloves"> 
<meta property="og:image" content="//wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/inv_gauntlets_05.jpg"> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.wowhead.com/item=10003/black-mageweave-gloves"> 
...
```

The element with the `og:image` `property` value seems to be what you're looking for.

You can read it using something like the following method (note that `select` works only for `body` elements):

```
private String imgUrl(Document doc) {
    for (Element m : doc.getElementsByTag("meta")) {
        if ("og:image".equals(m.attr("property")))
            return m.attr("content");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I didn't get an email about any replies to the post I made. Thank you very much for the help! I should have looked at the meta tags first before going through the actual divs.